# Fatal Exception: NSInternalInconsistencyException - Xcode

Tags: swift, core-data

for a Customer I should fix two crashes with CoreData.

- This NSPersistentStoreCoordinator has no persistent stores (schema mismatch or migration failure). It cannot perform a save operation.
- This NSPersistentStoreCoordinator has no persistent stores (disk full). It cannot perform a save operation.

There are no differences in the entities, the model is the same: I cannot reproduce the crash that I look on Firebase.

Everything seems correct: I have experience with coredata and have checked every possible problem of Migration, etc.

Any suggestion?

Comment: "disk full": You can't do anything against that. You could check the disk capacity and how many space there is left to debug. But if it's full, you could catch the error and alert the user that if he/she wants to continue, he/she needs to remove files from his/her device in order to your app to work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Could the singleton give me a problem?
That is, it might be different to declare
"var singleton = XXX.shared" and use like singleton.context instead of "XXX.shared.delete()"